# Map rand5 to number in range

Tags: algorithm, random

I Have a function called Rand5, that gives a random number between 1..5.
I call Rand5 three time in a row, so i have three numbers between 1-5. For example: `(1,1,1)`,`(1,2,5)`, etc.

There are 125 possible options, and I want to map the 125 options to numbers between 1 to 125.

So:
`(1,1,1)` map to 1.
`(1,1,5)` map to 5.
`(1,2,2)` map to 7.
`(5,5,5)` map to 125.

Can you help me with pseudo-code.

Thanks!

Comment: Notice that there is no *real* mapping. you can do whatever mapping you want.

Answer (score 5):

Given that you have your three numbers `(a,b,c)`, you can use this equation:

```
result = (a-1) * 5^2 + (b-1) * 5 + c
       = 25*a + 5*b + c - 30
```

This is based on `Rand5` returning number in `[1,..,5]`, not `[0,..4]` as some random functions do...

To add a little background explanation, this equation treats the three random numbers as a three digit number in base 5:

```
abc(base 5) = (5^2 * a) + (5 * b) + c
```

Comment: Thank! @shapiro yaacov how you change the equation if the rand5 return [0..4]?

Comment: `result = (a) * 5^2 + (b) * 5 + (c + 1)`